# How to generate skewed 2d loop in python

Tags: python, nested-loops

How to generate this loop in python syntax:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        (...)
```

Of course, this works:

```py
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if j > i: continue
        print((i,j))
```

But is there a more elegant way to say *let `j` be less or equal to `i`* in one line?

Comment: how about `for j in range(i)` ?

Comment: Cool! I was looking for `for j in range(i+1)` but this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok adding my comment as an answer, with a correction (`for j in range(i+1)` instead of `for j in range(i)`):

```py
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(f'i: {i}, j: {j}')
```

Does this help you?

Comment: That's exactly it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the number in `range` is the number which is iterated up to. Hence,

```py
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The range function `range(start, stop, step)` has three parameters. **start** is an optional parameter, that specifies the lower bound of the range. It defaults to 0. **stop** is a required parameter that specifies the not included upper bound of the range. **step** is a optional parameter that specifies the incrementation with the default value 1.

That means

```
// ...
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // ...
}
```

translates to

```
# ...
for j in range(0, i, 1):
    # ...
```

which can be simplified to

```
# ...
for j in range(i):
    # ...
```